# Frase estándar para el *doggy bag* en español

Tags: extranjerismos, anglicismo

Alguien sabe si existe una frase estándar para el *doggy bag* en español?

En USA es normal pedir el *doggy bag* en los restaurantes para llevar a casa la comida sobrante. La gente lo tiene muy asumido con la acción en sí, no con el significado de cada palabra: *la bolsa del perro* es el sobrante de la cena del restaurante. En Francia utilizan el anglicismo. En España, como no es una costumbre demasiado arraigada, no conozco una frase de uso habitual que defina claramente la acción. Creo que "la bolsa del perro" no es ni será la apropiada, en castellano suena muy mal.

Buscando en internet solo encontré reportajes que hablan de la incorporación de la costumbre, pero sin un nombre claro que la defina. Lo más aproximado es el *tupper*, pero que tampoco es muy explícito. Todas las posibilidades que se me ocurren suenan bastante mal:

- Los restos
- Los sobrantes
- Las sobras
- El tupper con las sobras
- La bolsa de las sobras

Debo incorporar el suplemento en un menú donde tiene que quedar claro en una línea de texto que el cargo es por el packaging o bolsa no incluido en el menú presencial. En España es obligatorio cobrar por estos envases, por lo que este suplemento no puede ir incluido en la consumición hasta el momento que el comensal decida llevarse lo que queda del plato. Ninguna de las citadas queda muy "elegante":

- Suplemento por *las sobras* xx €
- Suplemento por *el tupper* xx €
- Suplemento por *los restos* xx €
- Suplemento por *bolsa de sobras* xx €

*Take away* o *para llevar* se confunde con el servicio de comida para llevar sin ocupar mesa. Lo que busco es la frase que indique que el suplemento es por el envase o bolsa que transporta el resto de la consumición hecha en el establecimiento.

Answer (score 2):

¡Hola!

Personalmente, la frase que más he escuchado al respecto es "Por favor, ¿me lo pones en un *tupper* para llevar?"

De cara a incorporarlo en el menú, yo pondría alguna de las siguientes opciones:

- **Suplemento *take away***: cierto que aquí aparece un anglicismo que, si bien cada vez es más utilizado, no todo el mundo entiende el significado
- **Suplemento para llevar a casa**: es una opción más explícita de lo que supone
- **Suplemento *tupper* para llevar**: quizás sea la que menos confusiones cree.

Sea cual sea tu elección, creo que al final la gente te preguntará qué significa, ya que, tal y como dices no es algo a lo que estemos muy acostumbrados.

Answer (score 0):

En España, cada vez más va calando esa costumbre, incluso hay algunos restaurantes que si observan en general, que los comensales han dejado comida abundante son ellos los que llevan la iniciativa y directamente te preguntan ¿ **Se lo pongo en un tupper**?.

El año pasado, en España, se inicio un *Proyecto de Ley de Prevención de las Pérdidas y el Desperdicio Alimentario* donde los propios restaurante estarían obligados y tendrían que ofrecer esta clase de servicios alimentarios, sin embargo, desconozco si esta ley esta ya en vigor.

Por lo general, si este no es el caso, y por tanto, eres tú el que lo solicitas, habitualmente dices, al menos por aquí;

- Por favor, ¿ Me pone lo que sobra?.
- ¿ Me lo pones (señalando a la comida) en un tuuper (lease, *taper*) ?. Gracias.
- ¿ Me lo pones para llevar a casa? ó simplemente, Por favor, ¿ me lo pones para llevar?. y cuando te lo entregan, das las gracias.

Normalmente, la palabra más común y utilizada, al menos como digo, en esta parte del Sur de España, es "*...me lo pones..*". No he oído aún nada de suplemento ó suplementos para llevar, ni take away, para referirse en concreto a la comida que no se ha consumido y se lleva a casa del restaurante ó de cualquier otro lugar donde ofrezcan comidas ó tapas.

P.D. Aquí no te cobran los envases, por ahora, hasta donde se. Más bien se considera, si sale la ley, que sería una "obligación por parte del restaurante", incluso un incentivo para volver, no una carga que encima tienes que pagar.

De todas formas, como dedicado al marketing, si me pides un slogan te diría ; " Envase Alimentario Extra", "Extra Food Packaging" ó algo así, intentando, si me apuras, un acrónimo. Aunque desde mi punto de vista, después de un par de veces se sabe exactamente lo que es un "Envase Alimentario Extra", "Extra House Food".... y si me haces jugar con la imaginación un " Packaging Extra, House, Food". No se como suena en Inglés, pero en Español sería algo así como  "Pez", "Pehf ó Pehd", imaginando cuando alguien compra un "pez" y te lo dan dentro de una bolsa con agua", pues ahora es comida que te entregan para llevarla a casa, al perro ó a alguien necesitado....En fin, es por pensar...

Comment: La palabra *táper* ya se considera lexicalizada y aparece en la actual edición del DLE (https://dle.rae.es/táper).

Answer (score 0):

En México solo se dice "Para llevar", cuando se acerca el mesero.

> Me lo das para llevar
>
> Me lo pones para llevar
>
> Es para llevar

Usamos eso.

Answer (score 0):

En el centro de México tenemos la palabra "itacate", proveniente del náhuatl. Se usa más para referirse a la comida que te dan después de una fiesta o visitar una casa, que al contexto de un restaurante. Pero por su etimología sería perfectamente aplicable.